# Windows 10 Creator's upgrade: Start menu power options and list of wireless networks close too quickly

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1703

With the advent of the Creator's Upgrade came a lot of problems. The first of many being the Start Menu Power Button will not stay open long enough to click on an option (Sleep Shutdown Restart). When you click on the Start Menu Power Button you can briefly see those three options but the window closes so quickly and automatically that you can't click on them.

Now I have the exact same thing happening to the Wireless Networks selection window (down by the clock). You briefly see all the wireless networks available but the window closes so quickly you can connect to any of them.

Comment: So what is your question? This is not a platform to complain - you can send feedback to MS directly...

Comment: It sounds like your installation is corrupt.  The behavior you describe should NOT be happening.  If it has been less then 14 days since you installed 1703 I suggest you revert back to 1607 and see if the behavior you describe still exhibits itself.

Comment: I am aware it shouldn't be happening hence the question. This isn't happening on just one computer. It is happening on many and the only thing they have in common is that it all started after the 1703 upgrade. Obviously a problem with the upgrade and I am trying to fix it  and @TomEus that is the obvious question...

Answer (score -1):

There is a possibility that system files or user profiles broken during upgrade, then lead to your current scenario. On my three 1703 computers, don’t see the same situation as you describe, the drop-down menu function is fine.

Therefore, try to create a new account for test.

If power button and wifi list still have issue on new account, I suggest to execute an in-place upgrade, use clean 1703 ISO file. ISO can be download by media creation tool which comes from Microsoft website:

https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10

Good luck